# Variables from getters stay at zero in another class - java

Tags: java, variables, getter

So when I read a text file, I have this to read it in and assign to instance variables and getters:

```
public class ConcertInput
{   

 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 private int capacityM = 0;
 private int ticketPriceM = 0;
 private int capacityO = 0;
 private int ticketPriceO = 0;
 private int capacityP = 0;
 private int ticketPriceP = 0;

/**
 * Reads the number of the assigned concert
 * 
 * @return concertChoice 
 */
public int readConcertChoice(){
    System.out.println("Please choose your concert: \n 1. Maroon 5"
            + "\n 2. One Direction"
            + "\n 3. Pearl Jam"
            + "\n 4. Quit");
    int concertChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (concertChoice == 4){
        System.out.println("Invalid choice. Try Again.");
    }

    return concertChoice;
    }



/**
 * Reads the customer's first and last name
 * 
 * @return firstLastName
 */
public String readFirstLastName(){
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name");
    String firstLastName = keyboard.nextLine();
    return firstLastName;
}

/**
 * Reads how the order will be placed 
 * 
 * @return orderType
 */
public String readOrderType(){
    System.out.println("How is your order placed? "
            + "B for box office or P for phone ");
    String orderType = keyboard.nextLine();
    return orderType;
}

/**
 * Reads how many tickets are needed
 * 
 * @return numberOfTickets
 */
public int readNumberOfTickets(){
    System.out.println("How many tickets would you like?");
    int numberOfTickets = keyboard.nextInt();
    return numberOfTickets;
}
    public void openInputFile() {

    String fileName = "concerts.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine();

        if (line.equals("Maroon 5")) {
            capacityM = inputStream.nextInt();
            ticketPriceM = inputStream.nextInt();
            System.out.println(capacityM);      \\I have prints here just for testing purposes
        } else if (line.equals("One Direction")) {
            capacityO = inputStream.nextInt(); //
            ticketPriceO = inputStream.nextInt();
            System.out.println(capacityO);
        } else if (line.equals("Pearl Jam")) {
            capacityP = inputStream.nextInt();
            ticketPriceP = inputStream.nextInt();
            System.out.println(capacityP);

        }
    }
    inputStream.close();
}

public int getCapacityM() {
    return capacityM;
}

public int getTicketPriceM() {
    return ticketPriceM;
}

public int getCapacityO() {
    return capacityO;
}

public int getTicketPriceO() {
    return ticketPriceO;
}

public int getCapacityP() {
    return capacityP;
}

public int getTicketPriceP() {
    return ticketPriceP;
}
```

SO when I go to call upon these getters in another class, they are at zero. I think it is something to do with my loop? Here is how i call upon the getters in another class:

```
public class ConcertEvent
{
ConcertInput input = new ConcertInput();
input.openInputFile(); //This returns an error.
private int capacityM = input.getCapacityM();
private int capacityO = input.getCapacityO();
private int capacityP = input.getCapacityP();
private int concertChoice = input.readConcertChoice();
private int numberOfTickets = input.readNumberOfTickets();

public int concertM(){
    if (concertChoice == 1){
        capacityM = (capacityM - numberOfTickets);
    }
    return capacityM;
}
public int concertO(){
    if (concertChoice == 2){
        capacityO = (capacityO - numberOfTickets);
    }

    return capacityO;
}
public int concertP(){
    if (concertChoice == 3){
        capacityP = (capacityP - numberOfTickets);
    }
    return capacityP;
}
```

}

This is the text file being read from:

```
Maroon 5
15 //capacity
40 //ticket price
One Direction
10
50
Pearl Jam
20
30
```

To test it I have simply doing this (this is not how I am going to leave it for the finished program):

```
public class ConcertDriver
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ConcertInput input = new ConcertInput();
    ConcertEvent event = new ConcertEvent();
    input.openInputFile();
    event.concertM();
    event.concertO();
    event.concertP();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190107/variables-from-text-file-remain-at-zero-java

Answer (score 2):

On this case you really should post all the relevant code, but from what you posted it looks like you forgot to call `openInputFile()`:

```
ConcertInput input = new ConcertInput();
input.openInputFile(); // <-- missed this line
private int capacityM = input.getCapacityM();
```

Change your class to initialize the following parameters inside a method, you can't do that in the class body like that - it won't compile:

```
ConcertInput input = new ConcertInput();
input.openInputFile(); //This returns an error.
private int capacityM = input.getCapacityM();
private int capacityO = input.getCapacityO();
private int capacityP = input.getCapacityP();
private int concertChoice = input.readConcertChoice();
private int numberOfTickets = input.readNumberOfTickets();
```

Comment: When I insert that missing line, I get an error. My recent edit will show how I am trying to use the variable.

Comment: @user3029836 `while (concertChoice == 1){` if it become `true` then it will keep on running, making never ending loop. I think you want `if (concertChoice == 1){`.

Comment: @Smit Yes i realized that and changed it, but those variables still remain at zero after calling upon them

Comment: @user3029836 YOu need to provide more information. In current stage its not possible to tell you what is currenlty happening.

Comment: @Smit I will post the the full classes. It may have something to do with how I am testing it.

Comment: @user3029836 if the file you read doesn't have a line `"Maroon 5"` (without any trailing spaces and such) your code will not get in `line.equals("Maroon 5")` and `capacityM` might never have been initialized so when you try to execute  `capacityM = (capacityM - numberOfTickets);` you'll get an error. That's only a guess since you didn't share the relevant code...

Comment: @alfasin i have posted all relevant code, thank you already for your help

Comment: @user3029836 look at the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous comments, I think your code looks something like this in total:

```
public class SomeClass {
    // ...
    ConcertInput input = new ConcertInput();

    private int capacityM = input.getCapacityM();
```

If that is correct, then the problem is as alfasin stated: You need to call openInputFile() somewhere, and you can't do it there in the header because only assignments are allowed there. You need to use a constructor to call the method and assign the capacity. Something like this (you have to insert your real class name there):

```
public class SomeClass {
    ConcertInput input = new ConcerInput();
    private int capacityM;

    public ConcertInput() {
        input.openInputFile();
        capacityM = input.getCapacityM();
    }
```

And so on for the other fields.